# RecyclerView only displays first item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

So, I am creating a cocktail app, based on the https://www.thecocktaildb.com/ api. Thus far, I have only created a screen to display options based on the ingredient I put in the search bar (search bar is not done yet). Yet when I run the app, only the first entry is displayed

By putting `Log.e("TAG", "$position")` inside of my onBindViewHolder, of the adapter, I saw that the position variable never increases from 0

```
class CocktailsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CocktailsAdapter.CocktailsViewHolder>() {

inner class CocktailsViewHolder(val binding: ItemCocktailPreviewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


private val differCallback = object  : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CocktailsByBaseDto>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame( oldItem: CocktailsByBaseDto, newItem: CocktailsByBaseDto): Boolean {
        return oldItem.drinks[0].idDrink == newItem.drinks[0].idDrink
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CocktailsByBaseDto, newItem: CocktailsByBaseDto): Boolean {
        return oldItem.drinks[0] == newItem.drinks[0]
    }
}

val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CocktailsViewHolder {
    return CocktailsViewHolder(
        ItemCocktailPreviewBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CocktailsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val binding = holder.binding
    val cocktail = differ.currentList[position]

    holder.itemView.apply {
        Glide.with(this).load(cocktail.drinks[position].strDrinkThumb).into(binding.imgCocktailsMainRecyclerViewImage)
        binding.tvCocktailsMainRecyclerViewTitle.text = cocktail.drinks[position].strDrink
        Log.e("TAG", "$position")
        setOnClickListener {
            onItemClickListener?.let { it(cocktail) }
        }
    }
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return differ.currentList.size
}

private var onItemClickListener: ((CocktailsByBaseDto) -> Unit)? = null

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (CocktailsByBaseDto) -> Unit) {
    onItemClickListener = listener
}
```

I have tried both position and 0 (which makes more sense) inside `val cocktail = differ.currentList[position]`, but neither gave me a different result

Comment: THat means your getItemCount is never returning anything greater than 1.  Which since your differ variable never changes from what you've posted makes sense.

Comment: You are right. My api returns the following, so it makes sense why getItemCount returns 1

2022-08-29 22:32:04.752 15696-15696/com.example.mycocktailfinder E/TAGQ: 

CocktailsByBaseDto(drinks=[
Drink(idDrink=15346, strDrink=155 Belmont, strDrinkThumb=https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/yqvvqs1475667388.jpg), 
Drink(idDrink=17105, strDrink=501 Blue, strDrinkThumb=https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/ywxwqs1461867097.jpg), 
Drink(idDrink=14029, strDrink=57 Chevy with a White License Plate, strDrinkThumb=https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/qyyvtu146

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the class I had passed to DiffUtil.ItemCallback